# How to produce odd numbers using only a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers, increment

I must produce the following output using only nested for loops:

-----1-----

----333----

---55555---

--7777777--

-999999999-

I cannot use any while or if statements

Here is my code:

```
public static void printDesign() {
    //for loop for the number of lines
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        
        //for loop for the left -
        for (int j = 1; j <= 6 - i; j++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        
        //for loop for #'s
        for (int k = 1; k <= 2 * i - 1; k++) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        
        //for loop for the right -
        for (int x = 1; x <= 6 - i; x++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }    
}
```

This is what it produces:

-----1-----

----222----

---33333---

--4444444--

-555555555-

66666666666

7777777777777

888888888888888

99999999999999999

How can I get it to only produce the odd numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i += 2) {
   for (int j = 0; j < (9 - i) / 2; j++) System.out.print('-');
   for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) System.out.print(i);
   for (int l = 0; l < (9 - i) / 2; l++) System.out.print('-');
   System.out.println();
}
```

*Output:*

```
----1----
---333---
--55555--
-7777777-
999999999
```

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is very close to the correct one. Simply change the step of `i` in the outer cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Change your first for-loop increment value from 1 to 2.

> for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i+=2){}

Comment: I believe it is better to give a tip than the full solution.

Comment: Maybe but still the approach seems to be correct and the solution is quite close :)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a homework assignment.  But I'll give you the hint that the key is in the "for(" line.

Comment: I think there is nothing bad to help in this case. OP has shown effort and is very close to the real solution. Also there is a specific point OP is asking for. I believe question is fair and a good one.